# RAILS 3.2 - Nested resources has many : through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, has-many, has-many-through

Guys I am becoming completely nut on this...and can't figure out at all how come out of all this troubles.
I really need an holy help, or at least some suggestions about tutorial and guides about this problematic.

I believe that this is a very common task in many app, but I can't find nothing that help in this sense, not on stackoverflow, not on google, not on other rails forums that I know...I start to feel like a dumb!!!

**Problem**

(1) Models (the models that are involved)

User.rb
Item.rb (is nested in user: e.g. user/3/item/5)

(2) What I'd like to do

The current_user (the user that is logged in) can create an Item, and in the same form can decide to share it or no with many other users.

In this way, the item will be visible and accessible also for this users that we shared it with.

I understand that what is going to be involved here is:

(a) has_many :through relationship between item and user
(b) a joint table that we can call sharing (with item_id and user_id)
(c) eventually using different name for the user and use a :class_name to point to user

This is not hard to implement (and there are plenty of examples around).

What is really a mess, instead, is how build the controller (item controller), in order to perform in one shot, the creation of a new item, and the sharing operation (this means setting up the parameter in the joint table, and eventually create as many records as many users we are sharing with - array?)

And the other problem, that obviously is related with the controller, will be the view...how put all this in a single form, and allow the current_user to just click the button, and perform the item creation + the sharing operation?

Last thing, but not the least, how I need to deal with the fact that User is the same model of current_user??

I really don't know what I need to read or look up in order to let this work, I would love to see some example code,but at the same time I'd love to really understand the logic in all this, in order to be able to replicate it in other scenarios.

Please someone help me...I can't really move on in my app development without doing this, and this is also a crucial part of all the project.

Thanks so much for every small bit of help that I will receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have solved all my problems...that was not an hard task at the end (it's always easy saying that when you solved the issue:))

The only doubt that I still have is with the rails name convention:

Can be possible that using a name like sharing, for the joint model, that the final -ing is not very well handled by rails?

After many tentativeness performed to try to fix my problem, I discovered that everything was set up properly, and that just changing the joint table name from sharing to share, let the magic works!!!